# Is there a way to reach the DataMember of a BindingSource as a collection object in its own right?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, master-detail, datamember

Say we have a class of **Customer** and that has a child object of **Orders**. In our Winforms application we might bind the main form to a list of **Customers**. A grid on the main form lists the customer's **Orders**.

This all basic master/detail winforms. We can set the `CustomerBindingSource.DataSource` to our list of customers. The grid's `DataSource` is *also* `CustomerBindingSource` and its `DataMember` is a string "Orders". `Orders` being a property of `Customer`.

At run time I want to *reach* the grid's contents as a collection of orders. In my case (for various reasons) I only have access to the grid and its contents, I don't have access to the original customer (so can't reference `Customer.Orders`)

I would want to reach grid's list of orders using something like this pseudo code:

```
CType(CType(OrdersGrid.DataSource, BindingSource).DataSource, Orders)
```

However, of course, this won't work. In this kind of classic Master/Detail form the `DataSource` of the Grid is actually the `CustomerBindingSource` object, and the orders are just a `DataMember`, which I can only access as a string.

Is there any way to reach that **Orders** collection via the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (freehand typing):

```
var orders = ordersGrid.Rows.Select(row => row.DataBoundItem).Cast<Order>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that looks exactly what I need, but I need to look at it properly tomorrow when I'm back in front of my stuff. Also @DavidHall has a refinement of your answer which I need to study.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misreading you, then you should be able to access the current customer through the binding source.

```
Customer c = bs.Current as Customer;

if (c != null)
{
    Orders o = c.Orders;
}
```

You can also use the method GertArnold proposed, though you will need to modify his code since the DataGridViewRowCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable.

```
var orders = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() 
               .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem).Cast<Orders>();
```

Comment: I don't want to access the orders via the Customer object, that's key. I want to access the Orders list via the grid. The second part of your answer looks really interesting however. I need to look at it when I'm back at my work PC tomorrow.

Comment: @hawbsl why can't you access the customer object through the binding source? That would be the standard way of doing it. I've always tried to avoid accessing things through the grid - I find that leads to coupling business logic to UI code.

Comment: in our case the orders property of the customer might have changed in the time elapsed since the grid was presented to the customer. if the grid shows 4 orders we want to show 4 orders, not 3 or 5 due to a change in customers.orders